# eclipse does not find any C++ debugger

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am using Android NDK with eclipse. I have settled everything up to debugging android native code, using many QAs in stack overflow. Now at the end of setups, in the debug configuration there is no debugger known by eclipse in the list. You see the window in the picture below.

[image]

Following [this tutorial](https://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/), there should be `gdbserver Debugger` option in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tutorial you followed is a bit old, ADT supports NDK projects a lot better now.

Can you try adding native support to your project:
[image]

Then launching debug as "Android Native Application":
[image]

I've made a screencast some time ago to demonstrate this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjsC-lKUgM8

Comment: Thanks ph0b. Which SDK version are you using (I have rev21)? I do not have `add native support` in that menu. Moreover there is no native support in `Window->Preferences->Android`.

Comment: You don't have `Windows->Preferences->Android->NDK`menu ? I've got rev22 but support was there already in earlier releases.

If you have installed ADT manually in eclipse instead of using the ADT bundle, maybe you need to add the NDK plugin:

Install `Android Native Development Tools` from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ eclipse update site.

Comment: I have installed ADT manually. Already I had NDK plugin installed, while I reinstalled it now but nothing changed. Moreover, I updated my SDK to 22, but the situation didn't change.

Comment: the `add native support` button disappear after native support is added to the project, maybe that's the case here. You still can't debug your project as a Android Native Application ?

Comment: I made a new project and tried to add native support, but the option was not there. Debugging is still inactive for me.

Comment: If you still don't have a `Windows->Preferences->Android->NDK` option, that means there is something wrong with your ADT eclipse plugin. Have you tried a fresh ADT bundle ?

Comment: By using ADT bundle it works. However, still I have to disable `Code Analysis` since everything is unresolved for eclipse indexer. Thanks ph0b